# Memory Efficient and Speedy iPhone/Android Dictionary Storage/Access

Tags: iphone, string, memory, dictionary, mono

Im having trouble with memory on older generation iPhones (ipod touch 1st gen, 2nd gen e.t.c). This is due to the amount of memory allocated when I load and store a 170k word dictionary.

This is the code (very simple):

```
string[] words = dictionaryRef.text.Split("\n"[0]);
_words = new List<string>(words);
```

This allocates on start around 12mb of storage, iphone has around 43mb I think. So that + textures + sounds + the OS it tends to break.

Speed wise, accessing using a binary search is fine. But its storing it in memory more efficiently (and loading it more efficiently).

The text.Split appears to take up alot of heap memory.

Any advice?

Comment: What is that `"\n"[0]`? Couldn't you just use '\n'?

Comment: Real question now: why do you need a List instead of a plain array?

Comment: I estimate 170,000 words with (a hopefully overestimated) average of 10 characters (at one byte each) should only take up about 1.7MB. Storing the data as an array of char arrays should only take up about that much memory.

Comment: "\n"[0] is a requirement it takes a list.

- I use a list for Binary Searching.

Most of the memory is used in splitting up the list into words. Is there a way to optimise that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't count too much on how much memory these pre-3.0 devices have available on startup.  43 MB is rather optimistic.  Is your app just checking to see if the word is in the list or not?  You might want to roll your own hash table instead of using a binary search.  I'd search some of the literature and stack overflow to look for efficient ways to store a large dictionary with the particular word sizes you have.  A google search on hash table might give you a better implementation.

Comment: Its not the memory of storing the list its the memory used while its splitting it up into words. The search is a good speed otherwise. A hash table would just use more memory overall.

I need a better method of splitting up the string into words based on the delimiter (new line).

Comment: Your binary tree is using up memory because it has to hold all the tree in memory.  If you use a hash table, once you put the word in the table, you don't have to retain all the nodes to do a binary search, and a hash search should be almost as efficient, if not more, in some cases.  The key is to select a good hash algorithm that works well with your proposed data.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite. It will use less memory and be faster. Create an index on your words column and voila, you have binary search, without having the whole dictionary loaded in memory.

Answer (score 0):

First if **dictionaryRef.text** is a string (and it looks so) then you already got something huge being allocated (2 bytes per characters). Check this it might well account for a large (near half) amount of the total memory being allocated. You should think about caching this (the database idea is a good one, but a file could do to then use File.ReadAllLines in future execution).

Next you can try do a bit better than Mono's Split method. It creates a List and then turn it into an array (calling ToList) at the end - which you end up creating a new List from. Since your requirement (only '/n') is fairly basic I suggest you to roll your own Split method (or copy/paste/reduce the one from Mono) and avoid the temporary memory allocations.

In any case take a lot of (memory) measurements since allocations, even more for strings, often occurs where we don't look ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with Morningstar that using a SQLite backend for your word storage sounds like the best solution to what you are trying to do.

However, if you insist on using a word list, here's a suggestion:

It looks to me like dictionaryRef.text is constructed by reading a text file in its entirety (File.ReadAllText() or some such).

Instead of doing that, why not use TextReader.ReadLine() to read 1 word at a time from the file into a List, thus avoiding the need to use String.Split() and using tons of temporary storage space?

Ultimately that seems to be what you want anyway... and ReadLine() will "split" on \n for you.